# Animation in Jetpack Compose influenced by animator duration scale from the developer options

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I am a novice in Jetpack Compose and I have a simple animation in my Jetpack Compose app where a circle expands for 7 seconds and then shrinks for 7 seconds, using animateFloatAsState with animationSpec set to tween and durationMillis set accordingly. It runs as expected on the emulator, but on my physical Android phone, the animation happens too quickly. I found that the "Animator duration scale" from the developer options is speeding up the animation on the phone (it is set to 0.5x vs normal 1x). How can I prevent this device animation setting from affecting my app's animations?

I found this information from issuetracker.google.com: "Animation scale from settings expressed as a SateFlow

```
This CL introduced a MotionDurationScale CoroutineContext.Element. This
allows the duration scale to be put in the coroutine context used
by Recomposer. At the same time, user code can define their own
duration scale and add it to a coroutine context. It will impact
all the animations in that coroutine context.

Animation duration scale is now expressed as a global StateFlow per
application, with one ContentObserver that emits new values as
the settings change.

Fixes: 161675988
Test: Included. Also added a benchmark.

RelNote: "Horray! Compose animation now supports
'Animator duration scale' setting from Developer Options."

Change-Id: I5a4fc779a3fbfbcb2926ac1624cd679bb9b912ce",
```

But no idea how to stop the setting from affecting my app.